# Not able to change H264 profile to High from Main using FFMPEG API

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg, h.264

I am using QtFFMPEG wrapper(https://code.google.com/p/qtffmpegwrapper/) with Qt 5.4 and MSCV 2012. I want to encode a mp4 video from image files at 25 fps and high profile. 
I used the createFile() and encodeImage() functions from [here](https://code.google.com/p/qtffmpegwrapper/source/browse/trunk/QTFFmpegWrapper/QVideoEncoder.cpp)

I am using the below parameters:

```
pCodecCtx=pVideoStream->codec;
pCodecCtx->codec_id = pOutputFormat->video_codec;
pCodecCtx->codec_type = ffmpeg::AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
pCodecCtx->profile=FF_PROFILE_H264_HIGH;
pCodecCtx->bit_rate = Bitrate;
pCodecCtx->width = getWidth();
pCodecCtx->height = getHeight();
pCodecCtx->time_base.den = fps;
pCodecCtx->time_base.num = 1;
pCodecCtx->gop_size = 10;
pCodecCtx->pix_fmt = ffmpeg::PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
pCodecCtx->qmin = 10;
pCodecCtx->qmax = 51;
```

The FFMPEG variables are:

```
License: %s
 GPL version 3 or later
AVCodec version %d
 3476480
AVFormat configuration: %s
 --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
```

Now I currently get a video with below properties:

```
ID                             : 1
Format                         : AVC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                 : Main@L3.2
Format settings, CABAC         : No
Format settings, ReFrames      : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP           : M=1, N=10
Codec ID                       : avc1
Codec ID/Info                  : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                       : 4s 320ms
```

I want the profile to be "High" and the CABAC to be yes with 3 ReFrames. How do I achieve that? I tried setting the profile, coder_type and max_b_frames but did not help. At times the generated file did not even play. Can anyone help please. Thanks.

I also tried using the av_opt_set() way but could not find that function. Only function I have is av_opt_set_dict(), am I missing something - outdated FFMPEG or missing #include.

Tried this too, didnt help-

```
   ffmpeg::AVDictionary *opt = NULL;
   int iRes = av_dict_set(&opt, "profile", "high", 0);
   av_opt_set_dict(pFormatCtx->priv_data, &opt);
   av_opt_set_dict(pFormatCtx, &opt);
```

Please help.

EDIT:
I got a high quality mp4 by changing the qmin and qmax values and then reencoding the big sized output via command line. I will try to upgrade the FFMPEG as suggested by Ronald below. Please consider the question closed for now.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> AVCodec version %d
>  3476480
> ```

That version (libavcodec 53.12.0) is from October 2011, please update to something newer. As you can see from the [H264 encoding wiki docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264), your settings will work with recent versions of ffmpeg. (Also please share the rest of your code, you're just showing the code that sets your settings, but not any other part of your code, so I can't reproduce anything.)

Comment: For now I made it work using the qmin and qmax settings to get a high quality mp4 and then encoding it again via command line. I will upgrade to the new FFMPEG and try again. Thanks for your help :)